# Error with VBox

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox, kubuntu

Today I updated the kernel to version 4.14.2 then I run the Vbox then it said Error modprobe. Then error "Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.3-041403-generic"

OS: Kubuntu 17.10 64-Bit
Kernel: 4.14.3

Comment: Run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` from the terminal

Comment: As @George's suggestion will show, VirtualBox is very picky about kernel versions.